# For C++ vector initialization, what's the difference between "vector<int>v = n;" and "vector<int>v(n);"

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

(English is not my native language; please excuse typing and grammar errors.)

I'm trying to create a `vector<int>` object with known length `n`.

I knew that I could do this by `vector<int> v(n);` or `vector<int> v = vector<int>(n);`. However, when I tried to do it by `vector<int> v = n;`, I got an Compile Error.

In my previous experience, `vector<int> v = n` seems the same as `vector<int> v = vector<int>(n)`, but it proves that I'm wrong.

I've read the cpp reference and searched "C++ vector initialize with an integer" on stackoverflow but cannot find much useful information.

So what's the difference between the three ways? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about `explicit` constructors.

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
vector<int> v = n;  //this is copy initialization
```

The above is *copy-initialization*. But the constructor for `std::vector` that take `size` as argument is **explicit** and hence cannot be used here, and so this fails with the error that you're getting.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
vector<int> v = vector<int>(n); //this is also copy initialization
```

The above is also *copy initialization*.  But this time, there is a copy constructor of `std::vector` that takes a `vector` as an argument and so this works without any error. Here the vector named `v` is created as a copy of(*prior C++17*) the temporary vector on the right hand side.

Also note that from C++17 onwards, due to **mandatory copy elison**, it is guaranteed that `v` is constructed directly using the ctor that takes an `size` as argument instead of being created as a copy using the copy ctor.

##### Case 3

Here we consider the statement:

```
vector<int> v(n); //this is direct initilaization
```

The above is direct initialization and it creates a vector named `v` of size `n`. This works because even though the ctor that takes `size` as argument is explicit, it can be used in direct initialization.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int> v(n)` generate a vector named "v"

`vector<int> v` declare a vector named "v"

`vector<int> v = vector<int>(n)` means that you generate a temp `vector<int>(n)` and `v = temp` . "v" and "temp" have the same type `vector<int>` so you can use "=" on them.

But `vector<int> v = n` is `vector<int> = int` they don't have the same type.

Comment: https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/v7ikqDS5RCEktbhEoZpLAQgy80oU8uKtwWywsAZYRFPBCiisAaSra7lqrbn@g0RzEzPzFDQ0oTrBqksUbBVMrLlquf4DAA

Comment: Actually with C++17 mandatory copy elision, there is no temporary created in `vector<int> v = vector<int>(n)`.